# R: translate strings of numbers into strings of letters following a relationships table

Tags: r, string, function, translate

I have a vector `mynumbers` with several strings of numbers, say:

```
mynumbers <- c("122212", "134134", "134134", "142123", "212141", "213243", "213422", "214231", "221233")
```

My goal is to translate such strings into strings of letters following these relationships:

```
1=A
2=C
3=G
4=T
```

I'd like to encapsulate this in a function so that:

```
myletters <- translate_function(mynumbers)
```

`myletters` would thus be:

```
myletters <- c("ACCCAC", "AGTAGT", "AGTAGT", "ATCACG", "CACATA", "CAGCTG", "CAGTCC", "CATCGA", "CCACGG")
```

I'm thinking of a function like this, obviously not correct... I start to get confused when dealing with `strsplit` and lists...

```
translate_function <- function(numbers){
  map_df <- data.frame(num=1:4, nuc=c('A','C','G','T'))
  #strsplit numbers
  split_numbers <- strsplit(numbers, '')
  letters <- paste(sapply(split_numbers, function(x) map_df$nuc[which(map_df$num==x)]), collapse='')
  
  return(letters)
}
```

What would be the easiest and most elegant way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily by `chartr`,

```
chartr("1234" , "ACGT", mynumbers)
[1] "ACCCAC" "AGTAGT" "AGTAGT" "ATCACG" "CACATA" "CAGCTG" "CAGTCC" "CATCGA"
[9] "CCACGG"
```

Comment: oh wow I wasn't aware of `chartr`, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may use `stringr::str_replace_all` create a named vector from `map_df` to replace.

```
map_df <- data.frame(num=1:4, nuc=c('A','C','G','T'))
stringr::str_replace_all(mynumbers, setNames(map_df$nuc, map_df$num))

#[1] "ACCCAC" "AGTAGT" "AGTAGT" "ATCACG" "CACATA" "CAGCTG" "CAGTCC" "CATCGA" "CCACGG"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use it in a function this way:

```
translate_function <- function(numbers){
  map_df <- data.frame(num=1:4, nuc=c('A','C','G','T'))
  letters <- chartr(paste(map_df$num, collapse=''), paste(map_df$nuc, collapse=''), numbers)
  return(letters)
}
translate_function(mynumbers)
```

Output:

```
[1] "ACCCAC" "AGTAGT" "AGTAGT" "ATCACG" "CACATA" "CAGCTG" "CAGTCC" "CATCGA"
[9] "CCACGG"
```

But it's better without a dataframe:

```
translate_function <- function(numbers){
  letters <- chartr("1234", "ACGT", numbers)
  return(letters)
}
translate_function(mynumbers)
```

Output:

```
[1] "ACCCAC" "AGTAGT" "AGTAGT" "ATCACG" "CACATA" "CAGCTG" "CAGTCC" "CATCGA"
[9] "CCACGG"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d)", setNames(as.list(c("A", "C", "G", "T")), 1:4), mynumbers)
[1] "ACCCAC" "AGTAGT" "AGTAGT" "ATCACG" "CACATA" "CAGCTG" "CAGTCC" "CATCGA" "CCACGG"
```